# Lyx 2.3.4.2 spell checker not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: lyx, ubuntu, spelling

Recently I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in a computer and Lyx 2.3.4.2. The automatic "on the fly" spell checking is not working even though I have activated it, as seen below:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does non-on-the-fly spellchecking work? e.g., if you go to Tools > Spellchecker. Under "Spellchecker" is there an option to choose "Hunspell"? If so, does that work? How did you install LyX? Was it with the PPA or from the Ubuntu repos or did you compile it?

Comment: When I try to explicitly use the spellchecker it instantly says that there are no errors in the whole document, even if there are, and it closes. I installed Lyx doing sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyx-devel/release and then sudo apt install lyx.

Comment: You have installed Ubuntu and LyX, but have you installed `enchant`?

Comment: Good point. After ```sudo apt install enchant``` now it is working. In the past I had never have to install it separately.

Comment: Great! Seems like a minor bug in LyX. Ideally it would give a more informative error of "can't find enchant" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

As Fran commented in my question, I only had to install enchant. The solution was:

`sudo apt install enchant`

and now it is working.